# websphere 8.0.1 publishing ear error

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, publish

I have a problem to publishing my ear application in websphere application server.

What can be the problem, thank you
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just check out in admin console. the EAR may not installed.

```
- open the admin console
- the Applications and uninstall your app.
- stop the server.
- right click the server and choose add of remove projects and then remove the app from there
- start the server. and deploy your ear again.
```